# Unix Command to compare within file

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

Given a text file of cricket scores in the following format -

```
kohli | 80
sachin | 100
yuvraj | 60
```

How can i find the cricketer with maximum scores with awk or sed ?

Comment: `score`?  I thought that a *score* was always `20`.

Comment: Have a try at solving it yourself first, then if you can't do it, present your attempt and how it failed. Also, tag it with what you want to use - perl,python,awk,bash+sed would all be options.

Comment: `awk` can do the trick: https://sites.google.com/site/antialamas/awkoneliners

Answer (score 3):

does this line help?

```
kent$  echo "kohli | 80
sachin | 100
yuvraj | 60"|awk -F\| '{if($2>v){v=$2;l=NR}a[NR]=$0}END{print a[l]}'
sachin | 100
```

Comment: i had those in a file , say scores.txt, then ?

Comment: i had a scores.txt in which your echo part is written, how can i pass files content?

Comment: @vijayshanker then: `awk -F\| '...' scores.txt`

Comment: It's best to avoid using the letter `l` (el) as a variable name as it looks far too much line the number `1` (one) and so obfuscates your code. `print a[l]` could easily be mistaken for `print a[1]`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a .c file , read until eof , and save each number to a variable.If that variable is bigger than the previous , then this is the biggest number.When eof has been reached, you will have the biggest number (talking of C).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sort -nr textfile | tail -1
```